# boot2docker inside VBox

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, boot2docker

I would like to use `boot2docker` for `Windows` inside a `VirtualBox` `(Windows XP 64-bits, VT-x enabled)`.

I tried to start the last version of `boot2docker (v1.6.2)` but the `boot2docker` start command does not end, both using the `Boot2docker` shortcut or running directly `boot2docker` start in `Windows terminal`.

The "`boot2docker init`" actually works, but the "`boot2docker up`" outputs (I waited for one hour, still up):

> Waiting for VM and Docker daemon to start..............................................ooooooo

There is no failure, no message, nothing major in `Logs` from `boot2docker-vm` and its state is "running".

I tried "`boot2docker ssh`" in another `Terminal` but it fails with error `"error in run: exit status 255" ("boot2docker ip" fails with "Failed to get VM Host only IP address. Was the VM initialized using boot2docker?")`.

I guess this issue can be related to the usage of `Windows` inside a `VB` by contrast with "`native`" `Windows`.

Did someone already successfully use older versions of `boot2docker` inside a `VirtualBox`? Or maybe it is not possible...

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me once, and I did a

```
boot2docker delete
boot2docker init
boot2docker up
```

and it worked.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I did it several times but I didn't succeed to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

It is rather impossible to run boot2docker inside the VirtualBox as boot2docker is based also on VirtualBox and unfortunately such nesting is not supported - here is [feature request](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/4032) concerning this (its worth to show your interest there! :).

People are reporting [success running nested VirtualBox](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=63313) configuration but they are using 32 bit OS for inner instance and [docker supports currently only 64 bit OS](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/12149).

There are however some unofficial tries to [run docker on 32 bit OS](https://github.com/docker-32bit/ubuntu) but then there is a need of dedicated 32 bit docker images.

It would be interesting if such combination of above have worked for somebody.